# Tensor Product of Hilbert spaces

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, mathematics, hilbert-space, tensor-calculus

This question is regarding a definition of Tensor product of Hilbert spaces that I found in Wald's book on QFT in curved space time. Let's first get some notation straight.

Let $(V,+,*)$ denote a set $V$, together with $+$ and $*$ being the addition and multiplication maps on $V$ that satisfy the vector space axioms. We define the complex conjugate multiplication ${\overline *}:{\mathbb C} \times V \to V$ as
$$
c {\overline *} \Psi = {\overline c} * \Psi,~~\forall~~\Psi \in V
$$
The vector space formed by $(V,+,{\overline *})$ is called the complex conjugate vector space and is denoted by ${\overline V}$.

Given two Hilbert spaces ${\cal H}_1$ and ${\cal H}_2$ and a bounded linear map $A: {\cal H}_1 \to {\cal H}_2$, we define the adjoint of this map $A^\dagger: {\cal H}_2 \to {\cal H}_1$ as
$$
\left< \Psi_2, A \Psi_1 \right>_{{\cal H}_2}  = \left< A^\dagger \Psi_2 , \Psi_1 \right>_{{\cal H}_1} 
$$
where $\left< ~, ~ \right>_{{\cal H}_1}$ is the inner product as defined on ${\cal H}_1$ (similarly for ${\cal H}_2$) and $\Psi_1 \in {\cal H}_1,~\Psi_2 \in {\cal H}_2$. That such map always exists can be proved using the Riesz lemma.

Here the word "bounded" simply means that there exists some $C \in {\mathbb R}$ such that $$\left\| A(\Psi_1) \right\|_{{\cal H}_2} \leq C \left\| \Psi_1 \right\|_{{\cal H}_1}$$
for all $\Psi_1 \in {\cal H}_1$ and where $\left\| ~~ \right\|_{{\cal H}_1}$ is the norm as defined on ${\cal H}_1$ (similarly for ${\cal H}_2$)

Great! Now for the statement. Here it is.

> The tensor product, ${\cal H}_1 \otimes {\cal H}_2$, of two Hilbert spaces, ${\cal H}_1$ and ${\cal H}_2$, may be defined as follows. Let $V$ denote the set of linear maps $A: {\overline {\cal H}}_1 \to {\cal H}_2$, which have finite rank, i.e. such that the range of $A$ is a finite dimensional subspace of ${\cal H}_2$. The $V$ has a natural vector space structure. Define the inner product on $V$ by 
>   $$
> \left< A, B \right>_V = \text{tr}\left( A^\dagger B \right)
> $$
>   (The right side of the above equation is well defined, since $A^\dagger B: {\overline {\cal H}}_1 \to {\overline {\cal H}}_1$ has a finite rank). We define ${\cal H}_1 \otimes {\cal H}_2$ to be the Hilbert space completion of $V$. It follows that ${\cal H}_1 \otimes {\cal H}_2$ consists of all linear maps $A: {\overline {\cal H}}_1 \to {\cal H}_2$ that satisfy the Hilbert-Schmidt condition $\text{tr}\left( A^\dagger A \right) < \infty$.

My question is

**1. How does this definition of the Tensor product of Hilbert spaces match up with the one we are familiar with when dealing with tensors in General relativity?**

PS - I also have a similar problem with Wald's definition of a Direct Sum of Hilbert spaces. I have decided to put that into a separate question. If you could answer this one, please consider checking out that one too. It can be found [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70601/direct-sum-of-hilbert-spaces). Thanks!

Comment: I figured out the first problem. Removed it from question.

Comment: Concerning tensors, see also   http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32011/2451 and links therein.

Comment: If we consider only vectors, You will have a problem, because an Hilbert space has a positive definite inner product, while the tangent space of the space-time manifold has a pseudo-Riemaniann metric (Minkowski-like metrics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think Wald ever defines a tensor product for infinite dimensional space in his GR text, so I presume your question is about the finite dimensional case where we simply write the tensor product as the vector space over pairs $u_iv_j$ where $u$ and $v$ are a basis. I will show the equivalence in that case.

If we have two finite dimensional Hilbert spaces $H_1$, $H_2$ we can take the orthonormal bases $u_i\in H_1$ , $v_j\in H_2$. Since everything is finite dimensional, everything is finite rank, so the the vector space is just the the space of linear maps from $H_1$ to $H_2$. Take a linear map $A$ and define $a_{ij}= \langle A(u_i),v_j\rangle = \langle u_i,A^{\dagger}(v_j)\rangle$. Using the orthonormality of the bases that means $a_{ij}$ is simply the matrix presentation of $A$, and the vector space is simply the appropriate vector space of matrices. Then we can interpret $Tr(A^\dagger B)$ as the usual matrix trace which gives $\sum_{ij} a_{ij}^*b_{ij}$.

This is equivalent to the usual notation whereby we write tensor products as elements $\sum_{ij}a_{ij}u_i\otimes v_j$. Again the vector space is the appropriately sized matrices. The inner product is defined to be $\langle a\otimes b, c\otimes d\rangle = \langle a,b\rangle\cdot\langle c,d\rangle$. This gives the same result as above after plugging in the basis.

Comment: This is not from his GR text. This is from his text on QFT in curved spacetimes.

Comment: @Prahar: Yeah I know. It's just that you said you wanted to see the definition was equivalent to the "usual" one in GR, but you didn't specify what the usual one is. So I assume you meant the usual finite dimensional notation, as in his GR book

Comment: Oh! sorry. My bad.

Answer (score 6):

Let there be given a ([monoidal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category)) [category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_%28mathematics%29) ${\cal C}$, e.g., the category of finite dimensional vector spaces, the category of Hilbert spaces, etc.

In such a category ${\cal C}$, one typically has the isomorphism

$$\tag{1} {\cal H} \otimes {\cal K} \cong {\cal L}({\cal H}^{*}, {\cal K}), $$

where ${\cal H}^{*}$ is a dual object, and ${\cal L}$ is the pertinent space of morphisms ${\cal H}^{*}\to {\cal K}$.

Often textbooks don't provide the *actual definition* of a [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product), which is nevertheless at least partly explained on Wikipedia, but instead cheat by using the isomorphism (1) as a *working definition* of a tensor product ${\cal H} \otimes {\cal K}$.

Comment: @Qmechanics I'm wonder what is the "actual definition" that you're talking about. I mean, at least in finite dimension, dealing with real vector spaces, the tensor product is nothing more than just a vector space $V$ with a operation $\otimes$ that obeys the universal property.

Answer (score 1):

Wald defines the tensor product of Hilbert spaces which have not to be finite dimensional. Otherwise $V$ would be automatically a set of maps with finite range. $V'$ is the completion of $V$ i.e. its elements are equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences. So trace norm is extended to $V'$.
$${H_1} \otimes {H_2} $$
 is defined to be this completion.

The Dirac notation is useful to see how they match up.
$|R\rangle$ and $|S\rangle$ are vectors of $H_1$ and $H_2$.
They are associated to $\langle R|$ and $\langle S|$ (or their conjugates) by Riesz theorem.
The standard notation for the tensor product is $|R\rangle\otimes |S\rangle$ or $|R\rangle|S\rangle$.
Here Wald defines it as the map $|S\rangle \langle R'|$. 
The associated bilinear map is $\langle R|\,\cdot\,\rangle \langle S|\,\cdot\,\rangle$